# How to get AWS EMR SPARK UI using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, spark-ui

I am trying to use Spark UI in AWS EMR, without login in to the aws console. is there any way to access it using python program(boto3).

I have all credentials and everything apart from console access.

I went through all the materials in Google, but not able to find it.

Comment: Spark UI through python? what does that mean?

Comment: without opening the aws console, I want to view the History server(spark UI) which is available in EMR when running the spark job - (AWS console)